# Variable assignment in python from json output (wildcard)

Tags: python, json, wildcard

I'm currently working with a chunk of .json that is output from an API call.
I'm trying to grab certain pieces of this data and assign them to variables so that I can then use them in certain reformatted messages.

Here is an example of what my .json output is:

```
{
  "content": {
    "HTTP": {
      "obsess": "1",
      "check_command": "check_http",
      "active_checks_enabled": "1",
      "process_performance_data": "1",
      "last_state_change": "1421870740",
      "last_event_id": "1"
    }
    "PING": {
      "obsess": "1",
      "check_command": "check_ping!100.0,20%!500.0,60%",
      "active_checks_enabled": "1",
      "process_performance_data": "1",
      "last_state_change": "1373404110",
      "last_event_id": "0",
    }
}
```

Working with this output, I have created a variable assignment for some of the variables, but I cannot figure out how I should use a wildcard to substitute for 'HTTP, PING, etc'

```
service_name = (service['content']['[]']['last_state_change'])
```

Is this something that can be done simply? In some json calls, I know that .[] can be used as a wildcard. I have attempted replacing '[]' above with '*' and just [] but have not yet been successful.

My goal is to grab the same chunk of data (in this example "last_state_change") from every possible entry where 'HTTP' and 'PING' are located.

Any help would be appreciated, if this isn't possible by just substituting in something I'm willing to take any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to iterate over the resulting `dict`:

```
changes = {}
for x in service['content']:
    changes[x] = service['content'][x]['last_state_change']
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is two keys and you know exactly which those keys are, you could define them in your code as a list and only retrieve contents for those.

```
import json
test = '''{
    "content": {
        "HTTP": {
            "obsess": "1",
            "check_command": "check_http",
            "active_checks_enabled": "1",
            "process_performance_data": "1",
            "last_state_change": "1421870740",
            "last_event_id": "1"
        },
        "PING": {
            "obsess": "1",
            "check_command": "check_ping!100.0,20%!500.0,60%",
            "active_checks_enabled": "1",
            "process_performance_data": "1",
            "last_state_change": "1373404110",
            "last_event_id": "0"
        },
        "somethingelse": {
            "obsess": "1",
            "check_command": "check_ping!100.0,20%!500.0,60%",
            "active_checks_enabled": "1",
            "process_performance_data": "1",
            "last_state_change": "1373404110",
            "last_event_id": "0"
        }

    }
}'''
json = json.loads(test)
print(json)
keys = ['HTTP', 'PING']
for key in json['content']:
    if key in keys:
        last_key_change = json['content'][key]['last_state_change']
        print(key, last_key_change)
```

Comment: Thank you for this option, unfortunately the number of keys isn't static and needs to be flexible to any number of keys being passed.

Comment: This answered is tailored to retrieve only a set of desirable keys (like your question was formulated). If you want to dynamically build a list of keys and retrieve their last_state_change inner values, then the first answer is the one you want. Please note that both answers will fail if your JSON structure changes as they rely on hardcoded key names.